# Odoo security : My Module not found in the applications list when creating new users group

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, erp, odoo-10

Greeting;
I have created a new module named phpevaluation, and i want to configure security on this module (who use what), so i have to create a set of users groups to define my types of access, the problem is in the users group form , when I try to choose my created module from the list of applications I could not found it;

-I named the module phpevaluation (without dashes nor underscores)
-Inside my **manifest**.py file the application attribute is setted to True
-When I access using pgAdmin to the "ir_module_module" table I find the record and the "application" attribute is correction setted to True

I am using Odoo 10

Comment: what do you mean by `users group form`  you mean the form in menu  `setting -> usres -> groups `?

Comment: Yes,Exactly 
In real it was a fake probelm because the field "Application" in the form corresponds to an Application category not Application (or module)
so a users group (from the menu Setting -> Users -> Groups ) will be applied to a set of Applications (Modules)

Comment: Merci kho ;)
nice to meet you
[link](https://www.linkedin.com/in/bouzid-medjdoub-967330aa)

Comment: Hia s7aibi. Nice to meet you too but in security you should create ir.model.security file to define the model security for your models

Comment: of course, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In real it was a fake probelm because the field "Application" in the form corresponds to an Application category not Application (or module)
so a users group (from the menu Setting -> Users -> Groups ) will be applied to a set of Applications (Modules) not for a unique application, so if anyone want to make a groupd for a unique module he could name the **category** attribute in the **manifest** file the as the same of the application (module name)